# Is there any way to make a Java ResultSet/RowSet update when there are external database updates?

Tags: java, jfreechart, resultset, javadb, rowset

I have a Java Db database table that I use to display results in JFreeChart. There are two processes:

1. updates the table every 30 seconds with data obtained from a temperature sensor
2. creates a JdbcRowSet from this table, which is used to create a series for the chart

At the moment, the only way I found to get the new data inserted by (1) into the RowSet is by re-running the query. JdbcRowSet only reflects updates to those rows that are already in the set, and not any newly inserted ones.

Is there a type of RowSet or ResultSet that adds the new rows automatically? Or do I have to re-run the query each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JDBC, you will have to re-run the query each time. You *may* be able to achieve what you are looking for by using an ORM, such as Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have a look at hibernate.